# 'grunt test' opens and shuts down chrome browser

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, karma-jasmine, yeoman-generator-angular

I've installed yoeman and installed angular.js package using `yo generator-angular`.
When I run `grunt test`, it opens and closes Google Chrome browser suddenly without staying open for me to see the test log in the browser.

Following is the log that was generated in the command prompt:

```
F:\ng>grunt test
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp...OK

Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
directory .tmp/styles/
       create .tmp/styles/main.css (1.342s)
    Compilation took 1.411s

Running "compass:server" (compass) task
unchanged app/styles/main.scss
    Compilation took 0.232s

Done, without errors.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
File .tmp/styles/main.css created.

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9001

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.17 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "F:/ng/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 8.1)]: Connected on socket W7iPEP_K_IgMyK6WrKFt
with id 83112925
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 8.1) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of awes
omeThings to the scope FAILED
        Expected 4 to be 3.
        Error: Expected 4 to be 3.
            at null.<anonymous> (F:/ng/test/spec/controllers/main.js:20:40)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 8.1): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.053 secs)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Windows 8.1): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.067 secs / 0.053 s
ecs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-07-20 12:08:40 UTC)
concurrent:test     7.1s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 56%
autoprefixer:dist  373ms  ■■ 3%
connect:test       441ms  ■■ 3%
karma:unit          4.9s  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 38%
Total 12.8s
```

Please advise what is to be done to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: You're not supposed to see it in the browser, all the info is in your console. If you want a report, check out http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/coverage.html

Comment: What if we want to debug ? I added a debugger; statement in a test it() to no avail.